# Excessive noise in stepper current

Tags: current, noise, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am currently utilizing the TMC5160-BOB module to operate a stepper motor with a current rating of 2.4 amperes via the SPI interface. The supply voltage for this system is 29 volts.  I am encountering noise in the current waveform which results in excessive motor vibration and a noticeable loud noise. Can anyone explain the cause of this issue?

I am using the SPI example provided in the [library](https://github.com/tommag/TMC5160_Arduino) to run the motor.

[image]

I have added  0.1ohm shunt resistors in both coil paths to measure the current and using differential probing method.

[image: Current measuring method]

Comment: Please show your current monitoring circuit and explain what oscilloscope probing method you used.

Comment: Measurement setup isn’t ideal, but at 5 ms/division, it’s hard to tell. Can you zoom in? What happens if you wrap the ground lead on the probe around the probe to make the loop area smaller?

Comment: Try a lower voltage (12 V, kind of stepper?), lower speed stepping, and perhaps also decoupling power pins near the board.

Comment: You should also "close" your measurement loop (lowest minimum area please by twisting the wires).